# Searching with Precedence on Array Order

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

My gut feeling is that the answer is no, but is it possible to perform a search in Mongodb comparing the similarity of arrays where order is important?

E.g.
I have three documents like so

```
{'_id':1, "my_list": ["A",2,6,8,34,90]},
{'_id':2, "my_list": ["A","F",2,6,19,8,90,55]},
{'_id':3, "my_list": [90,34,8,6,3,"A"]}
```

1 and 2 are the most similar, 3 is wildly different irrespective of the fact it contains all of the same values as 1.

Ideally I would do a search similar to `{"my_list" : ["A",2,6,8,34,90] }` and the results would be document 1 and 2.

It's almost like a regex search with wild cards.  I know I can do this in python easily enough, but speed is important and I'm dealing with 1.3 million documents.

Comment: What do you actually mean by "compare"? Do you want to compare each document in the collection against all other documents? Or are you instead asking to compare a supplied array against those actually stored in the documents? These have vastly different approaches so you need to be clear as to which case you are actually asking about.

Comment: I've amended the question.  I'm providing an array and will be searching the collection for documents containing a similar array.

Comment: Iterate on all documnets and use some logic in code to do this, mongo is not provisioned for these kind of logic. You will have to design algo for this.

Comment: I suspect the best bet (as the lists are static) is to create a string version of the array and do a regex across it.

Answer (score 0):

Any "comparison" or "selection" is actually more or less subjective to the actual logic applied. But as a general principle you could always consider the product of the matched indices from the array to test against and the array present in the document. For example:

```
var sample = ["A",2,6,8,34,90];

db.getCollection('source').aggregate([
  { "$match": { "my_list": { "$in": sample } } },
  { "$addFields": {
    "score": {
      "$add": [
        { "$cond": {
          "if": {
            "$eq": [
              { "$size": { "$setIntersection": [ "$my_list", sample ] }},
              { "$size": { "$literal": sample } }
            ]   
          },
          "then": 100,
          "else": 0 
        }},
        { "$sum": {
          "$map": {
            "input": "$my_list",
            "as": "ml",
            "in": {
              "$multiply": [
                { "$indexOfArray": [
                  { "$reverseArray": "$my_list" },
                  "$$ml" 
                ]},
                { "$indexOfArray": [
                  { "$reverseArray": { "$literal": sample } },
                  "$$ml"
                ]}
              ]
            }
          }  
        }}
      ]
    }  
  }},
  { "$sort": { "score": -1 } }
])
```

Would return the documents in order like this:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : 1.0,
    "my_list" : [ "A", 2, 6, 8, 34, 90],
    "score" : 155.0
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : 2.0,
    "my_list" : ["A", "F", 2, 6, 19, 8, 90, 55],
    "score" : 62.0
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : 3.0,
    "my_list" : [ 90, 34, 8, 6, 3, "A"],
    "score" : 15.0
}
```

The key being that when applied using [`$reverseArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reverseArray/), the values from [`$indexOfArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/indexOfArray/) will be "larger" produced by the matching index on order from "first to last" ( reversed ) which gives a larger "weight" to matches at the beginning of the array than those as it moves towards the end.

Of course you should make consideration for things like the second document does in fact contain "most" of the matches and have more array entries would place a "larger" weight on the initial matches than in the first document.

From the above `"A"` scores more in the second document than in the first because the array is longer even though both matched `"A"` in the first position. However there is also some effect that `"F"` is a mismatch and therefore has a greater negative effect than it would if it was later in the array. Same applies to `"A"` in the last document, where at the end of the array the match has little bearing on the overall weight.

The counter to this in consideration is to add some logic to consider the "exact match" case, such as here the [`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/) comparison from the [`$setIntersection`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIntersection/) of the sample and the current array. This would adjust the scores to ensure that something that matched all provided elements actually scored higher than a document with less positional matches, but more elements overall.

With a "score" in place you can then filter out results ( i.e [`$limit`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/) ) or whatever other logic you can apply in order to only return the actual results wanted. But the first step is calculating a "score" to work from.

So it's all generally subjective to what logic actually means a "nearest match", but the [`$reverseArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reverseArray/) and [`$indexOfArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/indexOfArray/) operations are generally key to putting **"more weight"** on the earlier index matches rather than the last.

Overall you are looking for "calculation" of logic. The aggregation framework has some of the available operators, but which ones actually apply are up to your end implementation. I'm just showing something that "logically works" to but more weight on "earlier matches" in an array comparison rather than "latter matches", and of course the "most weight" where the arrays are actually the same.

> **NOTE**: Similar logic could be achieved using the `includeArrayIndex` option of [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) for earlier version of MongoDB without the main operators used above. However the process does require usage of [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) to deconstruct arrays in the first place, and the performance hit this would incur would probably negate the effectiveness of the operation.